# boost::bind thread for pointer to function with argument

Tags: c++, boost, function-pointers, boost-thread, boost-bind

I have a function foo(myclass* ob) and I am trying to create a consumer thread using consumer_thread(boost::bind(&foo)(&ob))

The code does not compile which I believe is due to my inappropriate way of passing the function argument to the function pointer.

```
class myclass{
// stuff
}

void foo(myclass* ob){
// stuff
}

int main(){
myclass* ob = new myclass();
boost::thread consumer_thread()boost::bind(&foo)(&ob));
// stuff
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone here elaborate on boost::bind and how to pass function pointers with function arguments?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code sample has some errors. This is a fixed version, where the return value of the call to `bind` is used as the sole parameter in the `boost::thread` constructor:

```
boost::thread consumer_thread(boost::bind(foo, ob));
```

But you can skip the call to `boost::bind` entirely, passing the function and its parameters to the constructor:

```
boost::thread consumer_thread(foo, ob);
```

Comment: Thanks.. I have some lack of clarity about when bind should or shouldn't be used, although I read up on it.

Answer (score 2):

That should be `bind(foo, ob)`.

However, I'm fairly sure that `boost::thread` has the same interface as `std::thread`, in which case you don't need `bind` at all:

```
boost::thread consumer_thread(foo, ob);
```